# distinguish nodes in negative cycle and nodes reachable from negative cycle

Tags: algorithm, graph-theory, shortest-path

I was watching this [video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=lyw4FaxrwHg&list=PLDV1Zeh2NRsDGO4--qE8yH72HFL1Km93P&index=21) about Bellman-Ford algorithm by WilliamFiset.

And he mentioned that there is a way to distinguish nodes involved in negative cycle and nodes reachable from negative cycle at 10:20.
This two kinds of nodes will cause negative inf distance in single source shortest path algorithm.

I wonder how to do this, but I can't figure it out.
I googled but google always lead me to the intro of Bellman-Ford algorithm.

In brief, is there a way to distinguish between nodes in negative cycle and nodes reachable from negative cycle?
And, is it possible to get from just modifying Bellman-Ford algorithm?

Answer (score 1):

1. Run Bellman-Ford algorithm over each strongly connected component (SCC), if a negative cycle is found in an SCC then all the nodes in that SCC belong to negatives cycles.
2. Run a multisource BFS or DFS over any node in each SCC with a detected negative cycle. All the reachable nodes that were not detected as negative cycle nodes in (1) will be reachable nodes by negative cycles.

The total complexity is O(|V| * |E|).